# IzPack Support: Jar files and TAR approach

Tags: jar, tar, izpack

I am working on bundling a product for distribution. It uses XML standards, JSON, JQuery, html, JavaScript, and contains multiple servers. It is not a pure-java application. I do not have any main classes. When I tried to create jar files, I couldn't open them. I got an error message that there is no main class for the jar file. As a work around, I am exporting a tar file instead. Is there a better approach?

Furthermore, I am using ant script to run the installation file. I am using:

```
<target name="install" depends="tarChmodCompilerListener">
    <izpack input="install.xml"
            output="IzPack-install.jar"
            installerType="standard"
            basedir="${basedir}"
            izPackDir="${izPackDir}" />
</target>
```

When I try to run the ant program, it doesn't recognize the izpack tag (I got this block of code from the IzPack wiki). I think I need a jar file to recognize this, but I do not know which one or where to find it. How can I get the build.xml to run this block of code?

I am working in a Mac environment. I am using eclipse and shell scripting. I wanted to use IzPack because it's installation programs work for exporting to Windows, Linux, or Mac. Is there a different program I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You must include the taskdef tag in your ant to be able to use the izpack tag.

It should be something like this:

```
<!-- IzPack Dependancies -->
<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${path.to.izpack.installation.folder}/IzPack">
        <include name="lib/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="izpack" classpathref="build.classpath" classname="com.izforge.izpack.ant.IzPackTask" />
```

Now it should be able to recognize the izpack tag.

Cheers!